# How to apply a perfect diagonal gradient on a button in .xml with two colors?

Tags: java, xml

when i'm try to obtain a diagonal gradient with two colors in a button recibe that:[the diagonal apply to gradient but not is a perfect diagonal in component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PAZD.png)
But i spect this: [perfect line in the component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGz8Z.png)

The code used is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners
        android:radius="?attr/size.button.borderRadius" />
    <size
        android:height="?attr/size.button.height"
        android:width="?attr/size.button.width" />
    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:startColor="#ff0000"
        android:endColor="#0000ff"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

Any help is welcome. Thank you in advance.

I try to apply a gradient linear, angle 45º